# List all the apps in the view

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am trying to disable background data for all the apps that are seen in Settings->Data usage through uiAutomator
I am able to get into Data usage page, bt not able to figure out how to get the apps and click then one by one. So that I can go inside and disable the background data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'uiautomatorviewer' tool and view the text/description/resource id of the apps being displayed there.

To use uiautomatorviewer tool :

```
[1] Connect your device.
[2] Open command prompt and type 'uiautomatorviewer'.
[3] Open the particular screen of whose elements you want to view (in this case - your data usage page).
[3] Press the green 'Device Screenshot' button  next to file open in top left.
```

[image: uiautomatorviewer_tool]

Comment: Thanks Smriti. But, what I was looking was to programmatic listing of the apps in this Data usage page. I need to disable the back ground data of all applications listed in this page except 2 of my own apps.